# how to update many-to-many collection (lazy-loading) in hibernate/spring?

Tags: spring, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have three tables and two classes.there are many-to-many relationship between the two tables/classes.

*OYS_USER -->Many-to-Many with 'oys_lesson'

OYS_LESSON-->Many-to-Many with 'oys_user'

OYS_LESSON_STUDENT-->relationship*


*in **User.class***

```
@ManyToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name="oys_lesson_student", 
    joinColumns = {  @JoinColumn(name="student_id",referencedColumnName="id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="lesson_id",referencedColumnName="id") })
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private Set<Lesson> studentLessons;
```

*in **Lesson.class***

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "oys_lesson_student", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "lesson_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private Set<User> lessonStudents;
```

I updated collection with below codes:

```
@Override
public void addLessonToStudent(Lesson lesson) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String username = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication().getName();
            Criteria criteria = openSession().createCriteria(User.class)
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("username", username));
            User user=(User) criteria.uniqueResult();
            log.info("'"+lesson.getLessonName()+"' lesson added to '"+user.getUsername()+"'");
            /*user.getStudentLessons().add(lesson);
            updateUser(user);
            */
            lesson.getLessonStudents().add(user);
            updateLesson(lesson);
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
@Override
public void updateLesson(Lesson lesson) {
    log.info(lesson.getLessonName()+" updated.");
    openSession().update(lesson);
}
```

When I added current user to lesson's collection (or lesson to current user's collection).
update/insert query does not appear in hibernate statistics(console-log).
So a record can not be added to any collection.
Basically,I want to add new object to many to many collection.What am I doing wrong?

- I use hibernate 4.3.5.Final (to get rid of lazy loading exception)
- I use org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter for rid of lazy loading exception).
- I tried CascadeType.EAGER with FetchType.JOIN.But did not change the results.update/insert query does not appear in hibernate statistics(console-log).
- I use below properties for hibernate in application-context.xml(spring-hibernate-configuration):

  ```
      <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
          <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
          </prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
          <prop key="use_sql_comments">true</prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
          <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/myehcache.xml</prop>
      </props>
  </property>
  ```
- and spring txManager:

  ```
          <!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

  <!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
  <bean id="txManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
  </bean>
  ```

  I use spring/security,hibernate 4.3.5.Final,jpa2.1,jsf2.2. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this jsf related?

Comment: no, you're not using JPA API either

Comment: What do you mean exactly?I use jpa 2.1 for hibernate 4.3.5.Final.Do you have any suggestions to solve the this problem?Thanks @Neil-Stockton

Comment: You are using Hibernate's API, not JPA API. There is no "Session" in JPA. There is no Restrictions in JPA, and on it goes.

Comment: What should I do so?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

Firstly, you need to decide which site of your reletionship is 'in control'. Is the user or is it the lesson. And yo define the join table only on one of them so for example:
- you leave the user as it is
- on lesson you changed

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="studentLessons" ...)
```

Then, you need to add the reletionship manually to both sites of the relationship (in reality adding to the one in charge of mapping is typically enought).

so

```
user.getUserLesseson().add(lesson);
lesson.getLessonStudents().add(user);
```

if both are issued inside transaction it will result in the insert

Comment: Thanks for reply.I tried above codes.But no change.When I coding "log.info(user.getStudentLessons().toString());" , I see all info (user's table columns,oys_user_lesson table info) and I see "select query" for this result.I see increasing the getStudentLessons list size.so far everything is normal.but then does not do the update process.I dont see update/insert query in console.So I dont see a record in oys_student_lesson table.:/

Comment: are you insed transaction? I am not using hibernate and spring myself, only jpa, for unmanaged transaction the code will be EM.getTransaction().begin(); User user = EM.find()..; .add(lesson);... EM.getTransaction().commit(); In Spring it is done by @Transactional annotation around the method or something like that (sorry not a spring user). Same way as you managed to insertpersist  new user or lesson.

Comment: I use @Transactional annotation in service class/layer.And I use autocommit.You can see in hibernate properties.Normally users can update/I can update.But when I add lesson object to user's lesson collection,not update.

Comment: It must work, the code looks ok, the mappings is ok (if you fixed the mappedby) and this is how it is done in JPA. So the suspect is your transaction/session. Try to modify a property of user/lesson in your addLessonToStudent method and check if an sql update is issued after the method exits. I guess there will be no update.

Comment: I checked manually change to user's name.etc before updateUser(user);.Updating only user(user table).hibernate behaving as if studentLessons collection did not change.

Comment: it doesn't make any sense, there must be a silly bug somewhere in the code that we don't see. The insert should happen when you add to the object that does not have mappedBy on its collection. What happens when you remove a lesson from the collection, it would be mental if that work but not insert. Are you sure you don't have a bug in your getters (for example always creating new set in them...). You can try to remove all the extra parameters from hibernate (cahces, bytecode), should not matter but ... I run out of idea how to attack it.